# Change the URL of a Azure Static Web App from the randomly generated name

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

I created a **Azure Static Web App** in Azure. The process saved a workflow file in the Github repository and created a URL `https://nice-beach-0253b8b10.azurestaticapps.net`. How can I change this URL?

Comment: You mean assign a custom domain like mywebsite.com?

Comment: I did not like the **nice-beach** in the URL. Until I get a custom domain, I need to use the URL like ```https://mywebsite.azurestaticapps.net```.

Comment: My guess is that `nice-beach-0253b8b10` is the name of your Azure Static Web App and was auto-assigned. Just speculating but can't you change the workflow somehow and assign the name of your liking?

Comment: I wish there is some way to do this. Linking related github issue: https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/346. An upvote might get it some attention.

Answer (score 6):

You currently can't change the azurestaticapps.net itself. However, you can configure a custom domain (using your own domain provider) or setup a CNAME record.

See more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain?tabs=azure-dns

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot pick and choose your app URLs. But if you hate only the **nice-beach** part, you can always create another Static Web App resource and hope for the best as Azure picks a random two-word phrase every time.

Answer (score -1):

Static web apps are just another Azure app service and you should be able to set up custom domains as you normally do for any other app service.

Comment: I did not like the **nice-beach** in the URL. Until I get a custom domain, I need to use the URL like ```https://mywebsite.azurestaticapps.net```.

Comment: @wonderfulworld You are one of the lucky ones. I got **proud-smoke** for mine :|